# return a new array of rankings of the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, if your input array is [10, 5, 20], the output should be [2, 3, 1], since 10 is the second largest number, 5 is the third largest, and 20 is the largest.
This is my function:

```
function rankings(arr){
const result=[];
let newArr=arr.sort((a,b)=>b-a);
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 for (let j=0;j<newArr.length;j++){
 arr[i]===newArr[j]? result.push(j+1): console.log('');
 }
}
 return(result);
 }
```

Using my function with this array [10,5,20] as my input, my output is [1,2,3] while
rankings([10, 5, 20]); // [2, 3, 1]  expected output
rankings([6, 8, 1, 12, 4, 3, 9]); // [4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2]  expected output

Comment: what about same scores?

Comment: Just change `let newArr=arr.sort((a,b)=>b-a);` to `let newArr=[...arr].sort((a,b)=>b-a);` to clone the array

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to `sort` the array, and then match the indexes of the original array.

Edited to cater the case of repeated numbers

```js
var originalArray = [10, 5, 20, 10, 20]
   , setArray = [...new Set(originalArray)]
   , sortedArray = [...setArray].sort((a, b) => a - b)
   , dataIndex = originalArray.map(d => sortedArray.indexOf(d) + 1)

console.log(dataIndex)
```

Comment: This would output weird results if scores are repeated, try `[10, 5, 20, 10, 20]`.

Comment: Yes @GhassenLouhaichi edited to cater this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the values and filter the items for avoiding same values with different ranks.

```js
function rankings(array) {
  const sorted = [...array]
      .sort((a, b) => b - a)
      .filter((b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => a !== b);
 
    return array.map(v => sorted.indexOf(v) + 1);
}

console.log(rankings([10, 5, 20])); // [2, 3, 1]
console.log(rankings([6, 8, 1, 12, 4, 3, 9])); // [4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2]
console.log(rankings([10, 5, 20, 10, 20]));
```